# Limiting products of realizations of an integer-valued Markov chain

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $(X_m)$ be a finite space discrete time irreducible and aperiodic Markov chain with stationary distribution $\pi$. The state space is a finite set of positive integers $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_l\}$.

1. What does $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left( \prod\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^{1/n}$ equal to?
2. Is it true that we get the same limit if we consider just the last $k$ realizations, that is, is it true that $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  \left( \prod\limits_{i=n-k+1}^n X_i \right)^{1/k}$ defines the same limit? (Does it exist for all irreducible, aperiodic discrete Markov chain or some more assumptions are needed?)

Comment: Since you have an ergodic chain, $\frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^n\log X_i\to E_{\pi}(\log X)$. Same for the second variation.

Comment: In fact, all you need is uniqueness of a stationary measure, so aperiodicity is not required.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you. And what about the second limit?  Is it true that it exists and agrees the first limit, why?

Comment: @A.S. So I didn't get why the uniqueness of a stationary measure implies that the second variation defines the same value. I mean, $\frac{1}{k} \sum_{n-k-1}^{n} \log(X_i) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}_{\pi}(\log X_i)$ in what sense? What does the limit define for a fixed $k$? The order of the limits requires some more work, doesn't it? Could you please clarify! Thank you!

Comment: For any $n$, $\frac 1 k\sum_{n+1}^{n+k}\overset{k\to\infty}\longrightarrow E_{\pi}$.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you. Yes, ok that is true but here the order of the limits is different.
Now you are considering $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac1k \sum_{n+1}^{n+k} \log(X_i)$. I totally understand that this tends to $\mathbb{E}_{\pi} (\log X_i)$. But it is not the same limit as I am dealing with.

Comment: The limit I listed holds for ANY $n$. Hence in your limit, if I take outside $k$ large enough, the inside expression will be tightly concentrated around $E_{\pi}$ and as $k$ increases, the concentration betters, leading to convergence.

Comment: @A.S. I am still not convinced. Are you sure that for large enough $k$ the inside expression will be tightly concentrated? I mean, let's assume that the Markov chain is as simple as possible (two states: 1,2  with $\pi = (0.5,  0.5)$.  Then still we will have a $k$ -long run of 1s and $k$-long run of 2s for any $k$. So the inside limit is not well-defined. Right?

Comment: Richard: Kudos for sticking to your guns and not letting dismissive comments discourage you. No, the second limit does not follow from the first, actually, in most cases, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  \left( \prod\limits_{i=n-k+1}^n X_i \right)^{1/k}$ does not exist, simply because  $\prod\limits_{i=n-k+1}^n X_i$ does not converge when $n\to\infty$. You may want to find a clean argument why it does not when $k=1$... and then realize that the same applies to any fixed $k$. Thus, again except in some degenerate cases, $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\ldots$ does not exist.